# Convert mongodb query to elastic query

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

We have an api biuld with mongodb as database. As the data is huge, we indexed all data in elastic search, so how can we convert mongodb query to elasticsearch query? Are there any plugins vailable? Please sugest

Comment: I don't know of any plugins. Can you give an example of the kind of queries that you are converting?

Comment: {"$and":[{"hc":{"$gt":0}},{"fp":0},{"$or":[{"robo":0},{"sima":0}]},{"$and":[{"f":1},{"t":0}]},{"bb":{"$in":[11557,11614]}},{"bl":"dp_public"}]}

same fields are indexed in elastic search also, need this conversion dynamically

Comment: Their DSLs for querying are completely different. I suppose you could make a tool to dynamically translate, but it would be _incredibly_ complicated. This is one of those cases where I wouldn't even try to do this and find another approach.

Comment: Yup, Trying hard for dynamically translating

Comment: Its done, recursive :-)

Comment: Hey @Steve did you accomplish this?

Comment: Yes i have accomplished by writing a wrapper class to covert mongo query to elastic query. That code was 2 years old, later i didn't work on that

Comment: @Steve do you mind sharing your code with me? Maybe we can finally solve this problem :-). sneeley AT  molecularmatch.com

Comment: Hi @Stephen, can you please share your code? we are stuck with same problem. It will be a great help. thanks

Comment: Well then Stephen, I guess I have to do it myself. Unless you share the code.