# how to execute mongosearch query on elasticsearch in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am working on elasticsearch.

The thing is the method I am implementing takes in a mongosearch query but I need to execute it on elasticsearch.

so far the mongosearch query will contain the criterias based on which i need to look.

is there any way to execute a mongosearch query on es ? or some way to change it to es query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch comes with its own DSL(Domain specific language), Hence MongoDB query will not work on the Elasticsearch, Although as Elasticsearch is built on top of Lucene, So for its [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) it supports Lucene syntax.
You can write your own converter to convert the mongoDB, although there are few failed attempts [here](https://github.com/Shane-Neeley/mongodb-to-elasticsearch-query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703101/convert-mongodb-query-to-elastic-query)..

If you like to use the advanced queries of Elasticsearch than writing your converter for those queries might be challanging.